# Firefox styles partially disabled. Colors, but not layout

Tags: firefox, styles

I tried to create a new firefox profile, but this person's firefox still brings up pages like this. Layout is ok, but colors and link or button formatting is not correct.

[image]

What setting is wrong here? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the result of High Contrast mode.

Start > Control Panel > Accessibility > Display > Uncheck "Use High Contrast".

Comment: Note that the Windows XP GUI is not affected. This is a Firefox only issue.

Comment: It is possible to pick the scheme it uses in High Contrast mode... although I think it may be limited to Windows Classic, in which case you do have a point. He created a new Firefox profile though, so it seems unlikely to be a Firefox setting.

George, does IE do the same thing? It also listens to the High Contrast setting.

Comment: Chrome does not, don't know about IE. I can check next time I am there.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is overriding colors. To disable this and fix your issue, make sure that you **check**

```
Allow pages to choose their own colors, instead of my selections above
```

under **Options > Content > Fonts & Colors > Colors**.

[image: colors]

***Note:*** you can access this dialog directly by going to:

```
chrome://browser/content/preferences/colors.xul
```

---

Alternatively, you can set the following preference in `about:config` to **true**:

```
browser.display.use_document_colors
```

---

**Example:**

[image: example]